# Executing Python file in Visual Studio 2017 works, but not when I execute it via cmd

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio project. It contains several Python files. One of them is the main.py. It is working great when I right-click the main.py file in Visual Studio, and start it "with/without Debugging".

But if try to run it via cmd like this: "python main.py" 
it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from units.predefined import define_units
ImportError: No module named units.predefined
```

Somehow it does not find the modules when I try to execute the Python file via cmd. Does someone know why it is not finding the modules? It would be great if someone could help me :)

Comment: Full Traceback please?

Comment: sorry i have updated my post. you can see the full traceback now

Comment: Maybe some "library directory" issue?

Comment: i have set up the modules in the Search Paths of Visual Studio. I think thats the problem. But i dont know how to run it via cmd or a bat file. Any solutions?